# Does the first precept require me to check the shower for bugs and make sure to remove all of the bugs before using it?

Tags: theravada, five-precepts, sila, killing

I recently noticed that perhaps fewer than 10 bugs seem to be in my shower.  I can try to remove all of the bugs from the shower before using it so that they don’t get washed away and killed.  However, some of the bugs are very small and hard to see, so I can’t be sure I can remove all of them.  Also, even if I remove all of the bugs in the shower, it is possible bugs will return, so I don’t know if I need to check the shower for bugs before each time that I use it.

Answer (score 4):

> I recently noticed that perhaps fewer than 10 bugs seem to be in my shower.

The reason many bugs show up in one place is usually due to that place having "things" that attract them, whether it's smell, shed skin cells (as their food source), humidity (their suitable dwelling environment), etc. So, instead of doing it the hard way, try tackling the issue at its root cause, try to keep the shower clean, free of residues, or humidity, etc. after you've finished using the shower, and you won't have to worry much about those bugs the next time you use it.

Answer (score 2):

The intention is important as outlined in the story below.

> The Story of Thera Cakkhupala
>
> While residing at the Jetavana monastery in Savatthi, the Buddha
> uttered Verse (1) of this book, with reference to Cakkhupala, a blind
> thera.On one occasion, Thera Cakkhupala came to pay homage to the Buddha at the Jetavana monastery. One night, while pacing up and down in meditation, the thera accidentally stepped on some insects. In the morning, some bhikkhus visiting the thera found the dead insects. They thought ill of the thera and reported the matter to the Buddha. The Buddha asked them whether they had seen the thera killing the insects. When they answered in the negative, the Buddha said, "Just as you had not seen him killing, so also he had not seen those living insects. Besides, as the thera had already attained arahatship he could have no intention of killing and so was quite innocent."

May you find peace! With metta :)

source: http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=001

Comment: Well in the case of Arahat Chakkulapa, there was no bad kamma because he was already an Arahat. But anyone who isn't an Arahat still gains bad kamma even if you do not volitionally kill a being. Although the bad kamma is very less when compared to intentional killing.